# Notification Backstack

Tags: java, android

I just added notifications to my app recently. I tried to fix the backstack of the notification after a user clicks on it but it was a bit of a failure.

I even tried to look into the documentation but it was without any progress.
The source : https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack

Thanks for any future help.

The code of the Notification before:

```
public void Test(View view){
        Intent trainingStarterIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent= PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0,trainingStarterIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Notifications.CHANNEL_1_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle("Get ready!")
                .setContentText("New day, new beginning!")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();

        mNotificationManagerCompat.notify(1,notification);
    }
```

The code of the Notification after:

```
public void Test(View view){
        Intent trainingStarterIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(trainingStarterIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Notifications.CHANNEL_1_ID);
        builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        //I even tried to fix it this simple way but it obviosly didnt work

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Notifications.CHANNEL_1_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle("Get ready!")
                .setContentText("New day, new beginning!")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();

        mNotificationManagerCompat.notify(1,notification);
    }
```

Comment: I don't get you, what's your problem?

Comment: After all this code it still doesnt fix the backstack so I have 2 MainActivities opened at the same time. I want to close all of the other MainActivities a open the newest one.

Comment: did you try trainingStarterIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); ?

Comment: Yes I did, its also written in the code above